# How sys.path is being filled?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, sys, pythonpath

I am running a python script to help me to learn how sys.path is being created. [In docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path), says the following:

- The directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified).
- PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
- The installation-dependent default.

I guess I understant the first two bullet points, but when I run `/usr/bin/python3.7 main.py` I don't know why the 
the highlighted directories appears. Is it related to the installation-dependent default? If yes, what is exactly this directories?
[image: my output]

```
    import sys
    import os

    try:
        user_paths = os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)
    except KeyError:
        user_paths = []

    print('PYTHONPATH:' + str(user_paths))

    print('---')

    for dir in sys.path:
        print(dir)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the [site](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html) module does most of that

Comment: @alexyorke There's nothing wrong with how `PYTHONPATH` is being used here; the `KeyError` simply indicates that `PYTHONPATH` isn't in the environment and so that none of the directories in `sys.path` are there because they were specified via `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: `sys.path` shows folders in which `import` searchs modules and it depends on version which you run. Python 3.6 has modules in different folders then 3.7. Also 3.8 will have modules in different folders. You have it as point `"The installation-dependent default."` And these folder on screen shows in which folders Python 3.7 has modules.

Comment: @furas The docs says 'When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name.' The built-in module is located in these folders? (edit: I guess I am misunderstanding built-in modules and the lib modules I guess)

Comment: there are located all modules - built-in (installed with Python) and installed later with `pip`. And also installed with `apt` or similar Linux command. Simply go to these folders to see what is inside.

Comment: BTW: in other languages is used word `lib` or `library` and in Python is used word `module` but it means the same as library which you load to get new functions. But it can also mean all modules which you have installed or all modules which are installed with Python (it is standard library)

Comment: @furas Is there a difference between built-in modules and the standard library? I mean, in the docs says 'the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name', for example I would say 'sys' is a built-in module because it is attached to the python interpreter (I could not find sys.py in the folders but I can find random.py). And a standard library example could be 'random.py' located in the installation-dependent default? I'm sorry if I wasn't clear, English is not my first language.

Comment: "built-in modules" means modules created with C/C++ - which can be inside `python.exe` - like `sys` - and this is why you can't find it. To find normal modules you can use `__file__` - ie. `print( os.__file__ )`. See [Standard Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#standard-modules). There is mentioned `sys`.